# window.closed is always true

Tags: javascript, window.closed

I'm opening a child window to another site where I don't control the content. I've implemented the pattern I found here of using a set timeout to check the window.closed property.

I've found this confirmed bug report for edge. [Edge Issue Report](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/15030423/)

Here is the code as it sits now.

```
var myWindow = window.open(
      url,
      'myWindow',
      'height=700,width=800,left=10,top=10,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=yes');  

// Check for the myWindow to close. When closed attempt to validate.
var timer = setInterval(checkWindow, 1000);

function checkWindow() {
debugger;
    // Try Block to catch our popup window being blocked
    try {           
        if(myWindow.closed) {
            clearInterval(timer);
            //do stuff here
        }
    }
    catch(e) {

        clearInterval(timer);
        //handle blocked popups and other stuff         
    }
}
```

when it hits the debugger step and I check myWindow.closed it is always true. In chrome it is false until I actually close the child window. Is there a work around or different pattern people are using?

Comment: Access is more restricted when the window is in a different domain. I'm surprised any browser allows this.

Comment: It is a read only property of an object the parent window created. It's also acknowledged as a bug in edge. I am aware that there are more restrictions to cross domain pages but knowing if the window still exists is still available according to the javascript specification.

Answer (score 2):

Take into account, that [window.closed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/closed) always returns true, if the newly opened URL isn't from the same origin / domain as it is opened from:

> [If the newly opened browsing context does not share the same origin, the opening script will not be able to interact (reading or writing) with the browsing context's content.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open#same-origin_policy)